# Observable from iterable doesn't print all elements

Tags: java, observable, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm using RxJava2 Observable.fromIterable() in a Rest web service.
My example iterable is composed of three elements but my Non-Blocking rest service returns just one element on three.

```
class ToDoDaoImpl implements ToDoDao {
  Map<String, ToDo> toDos;
  ...
  public Observable<ToDo> readAll() {
    return Observable.fromIterable(toDos.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> entry.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }
}
```

When I call the readAll() method from my Non-Blocking Rest library, I only get one element on three:

```
@Api(path = "/api/v2/read", method = "GET", produces = "application/json")
Action readAllToDos = (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) -> {
    Observable.just(request)
            .flatMap(req -> toDoDao.readAll())
            .subscribe(output  -> toJsonResponse(request, response, new ResponseDto(200, output)),
                       error   -> toJsonResponse(request, response, new ResponseDto(200, error))
            );
};
```

My Output:

```
{
"status": 200,
"response": {
    "id": "5dc74dd8-1ea9-427e-8bb7-482cc6e24c71",
    "title": "learn ReactiveJ",
    "description": "learn to use ReactiveJ library",
    "date": {
        "year": 2018,
        "month": 10,
        "day": 29
    }
},
"datetime": "Oct 29, 2018 4:19:51 PM"
}
```

If I call the Non-reactive equivalent of my Dao, instead I get what I expect:

```
{
"status": 200,
"response": [
    {
        "id": "25cbe3bf-12be-42e4-82ce-d4780f6469f6",
        "title": "study reactive",
        "description": "learn reactive programming",
        "date": {
            "year": 2018,
            "month": 10,
            "day": 29
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "51879241-f005-43fa-80fb-78386b663cb7",
        "title": "learn ReactiveJ",
        "description": "learn to use ReactiveJ library",
        "date": {
            "year": 2018,
            "month": 10,
            "day": 29
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "80a07c1b-2317-4eb8-9a39-ac35260f37a2",
        "title": "exercise",
        "description": "do some exercises",
        "date": {
            "year": 2018,
            "month": 10,
            "day": 29
        }
    }
],
"datetime": "Oct 29, 2018 4:37:05 PM"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `doOnNext` before subscribe you'll see that you get multiple elements, but apparently toJsonResponse can only deliver one. I bet your non-reactive version simply passed the whole `List` to `ResponseDto`.

I'm not sure why you complicated the task but this should work:

```java
class ToDoDaoImpl implements ToDoDao {
    Map<String, ToDo> toDos;
    // ...
    public Observable<List<ToDo>> readAll() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> new ArrayList<>(toDos.values()));
    }
}

@Api(path = "/api/v2/read", method = "GET", produces = "application/json")
Action readAllToDos = (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) -> 
{
    toDoDao.readAll()
        .subscribe((List<ToDo output)  -> 
            toJsonResponse(request, response, new ResponseDto(200, output)),
                   error   -> 
            toJsonResponse(request, response, new ResponseDto(200, error))
        );
};
```